# APA style citation of book with organization as author

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style, apacite

I want to cite in APA style a book with organization as author. The correct reference style should be something like the following:

> American Psychological Association. (2010). *Publication manual of the American Psychological Association* (6th ed.). Washington, DC: Author.

However, when I use `apacite` package and the following .bib file:

```
@book{1_americanpsychologicalassociation_2010,
author={American Psychological Association},
title={Publication manual of the American Psychological Association},
place={Washington, DC},
edition={6},
publisher={Author},
year={2010}
}
```

Latex will automatically separate the first name and last name of the author so the output becomes:

> Association, A. P. (2010).*Publication manual of the American Psychological Association*. Author,6 edition.

Two questions:

1. How do I make the author correct (it should be American Psychological Association instead of Association, A. P.)?
2. The output also missed "(6th ed.). Washington, DC: Author.". How do I make this part correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I make the author correct (it should be American Psychological Association instead of Association, A. P.)?

- Because you wrote

  ```
  author={American Psychological Association},
  ```

  BibTeX mis-interprets the author has having first name "American", middle name "Psychological", and surname "Association". Clearly this isn't what you want. To indicate to BibTeX that it's dealing with a single, "corporate" author, you should write the author field as

  ```
  author={{American Psychological Association}},
  ```

  Observe the extra pair of curly braces, which make BibTeX think that there's a single author who has just a (three-component) surname but no first and middle names.
- Because the `apacite` bibliography style practices so-called "sentence style", writing the title field as

  ```
  title={Publication manual of the American Psychological Association},
  ```

  isn't correct, as the three words "American", "Psychological", and "Association" are all converted to lowercase. You should write

  ```
  title={Publication manual of the {American Psychological Association}},
  ```

  The presence of the extra curly braces prevents the lowercasing operation.

> The output also missed "(6th ed.). Washington, DC: Author.". How do I make this part correct?

- `apacite` does not recognize a field called `place`. You should use `address` as the field name.

---

I believe the following MWE, which implements these comments, delivers exactly what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{1_americanpsychologicalassociation_2010,
  author   = {{American Psychological Association}},
  title    = {Publication manual of the {American Psychological Association}},
  address  = {Washington, DC},
  edition  = {6},
  publisher= {Author},
  year     = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{document}
\cite{1_americanpsychologicalassociation_2010}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```